# A commutative ring $R$ is local if and only if, for all $r,s\in R$, $r+s=1$ implies $r$ or $s$ is a unit.

Tags: ring-theory

> A commutative ring $R$ is local if and only if, for all $r,s\in R$, $r+s=1$ implies $r$ or $s$ is a unit.

How to start upon this problem?

Comment: What is your definition of a local commutative ring, firstly?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $r$ is not a unit, what do you know about $(r)$? And if neither is a unit, then what does $r+s=1$ tell you?

Comment: If r is not a unit, $1\notin (r) \implies (r)\neq R$, so?

Comment: But then $r+s=1\in (r) \implies (r) = R$ which is a contradiction

Comment: @Bosnia: Why is $r+s\in (r)$? That's certainly not right. Better to follow the contradiction argument I was suggesting. (Also, what does it mean for a $R$ to be a local ring?)

Comment: A local ring is one that has only one maximal ideal. And yes $r+s \notin (r)$, what is your argument?

Comment: @Bosnia: If for some nonunits $r$ and $s$ we have $r+s=1$, then both $(r)$ and $(s)$ will be maximal ideals, and the ideals will be distinct.