# Distinct, Nonunit Elements Form Two Distinct Maximal Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative unital ring containing two non-units $r$ and $s$ satisfying $r+s=1$. I am trying to show that $(r)$ and $(s)$ form distinct maximal ideals in $R$. That they are distinct is obvious, but I am having trouble showing they are maximal ideals. I could use a hint.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you've misunderstood the hint at [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/733186/29335). There is no reason to expect $(r)$ or $(s)$ to be maximal, much less distinct and maximal, especially not in a local ring. The point is that $(r)$ and $(s)$ would both be proper, hence contained in the unique maximal ideal (of the local ring in that post) and that would contradict $r+s=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $r=6$, and $s=-5$. Then $(r)$ is not maximal since $(6) \subseteq (2) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ with both inclusions being proper.

Comment: Hmm...So is Ted Shifrin's answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733175/a-commutative-ring-r-is-local-if-and-only-if-for-all-a-b-in-r-rs-1-impl) question wrong? I proved the problem given in the link differently, but when I came across Ted's solution I was interested in proving it his way.

Comment: That question deals with local rings, and his "answer" is just a question. I'm pretty sure the counterexample I just presented is valid.

Comment: I'm partially confused what you're trying to get at. His comment is exactly your question. If you are asking if the question you asked is wrong, then I will say "yes", since I literally just gave a counter example.

Comment: Answer is spot on already, but it's even possible to do it with neither element generating a maximal ideal ($(-5)$ is maximal). You could use $-8$ and $9$, for example. Actually, any pair of coprime composites would do.